# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean HasFlag(System.Enum)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: linq

I have this service:

```
//seroiunoiweucroewr
///wercewrwerwerwer
//wcererewrwerwer
public List<UserRoleContract> GetRolePagesByUserId(long plngUserId, DisplayType displayType)
{            
    List<UserRoleContract> result = new List<UserRoleContract>();            
    using (CitiCallEntities context = new CitiCallEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            //var DisplayList = Utility.GetEnumDescriptions(typeof(DisplayType)).ToList();

            //var selectValue = DisplayList.Where(i => i.Key == (byte) DisplayType.Windows).FirstOrDefault();

            result = (from oUser in context.User

                      join oUserRole in context.UserRole on oUser.Id equals oUserRole.UserId

                      join oRoleRightsPage in context.RoleRightsPage.Where(i => i.IsActive == true) 
                      on oUserRole.RoleId equals oRoleRightsPage.RoleId
                      join oApplicationPage in context.ApplicationPage.Where(i => i.IsActive == true) 
                      on oRoleRightsPage.PageId equals oApplicationPage.Id

                      join oRole in context.Role on oUserRole.RoleId equals oRole.Id

                      join oEmployee in context.Employee on oUser.EmployeeId equals oEmployee.Id
                      join oSection in context.Section on oEmployee.SectionId equals oSection.Id
                      where oUser.IsActive == true && oUser.Id == plngUserId
                      && oRole.IsActive == true && (((DisplayType)oRoleRightsPage.DisplayType).HasFlag(displayType))

//am getting error in has flag 
// am having three display type web, windows and all 
// how to overcome
                      select new UserRoleContract
                      {
                          UserId = oUser.Id,
                          RoleId = oRole.Id,
                          RoleName = oRole.RoleName,
                          PageID = oApplicationPage.Id,
                          PageName = oApplicationPage.PageName,
                          IsOPsCtrl = oRole.IsOPsCtrl,
                          ISOPsCtrlFor = oRole.OPsCtrlFor,
                          SectionId = oSection.Id,
                          DisplayType = oRoleRightsPage.DisplayType,
                      }).Distinct().ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            HandleExpcetion(exception);
            //throw new CitiCallException(exception.Message);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am getting Linq error in has flag conversion, how do I overcome this problem?

Comment: in linq you can't call function even if you try to call ToList() function inside query i will raise error . the best way is to create variable for holding function and then call these variables from your linq

Comment: try solution....might help to resolve issue

Comment: how to create variables?

Answer (score 0):

you are geeting error because HasFlag method is not paresent in database i.e. it might be part of language or local function in code which is not present in database.

So when query is translated it found this method is not available and that is the reason you are getting error.

one solution to avoid this error is

1. Brind all data from databae
2. Than filter than data, i.e. apply HasFlag method of it.

But this will bring all data and might decrease performance.

Example is

remove this line `(((DisplayType)oRoleRightsPage.DisplayType).HasFlag(displayType)` from your query

```
var list = querieddata //first fetch data without hasflag condition/method 
                   .AsEnumerable() // Rest of the query in-process
                   .Where(oRoleRightsPage=> ((DisplayType)oRoleRightsPage.DisplayType).HasFlag(displayType))//apply condition here once fetching done
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: querieddata does not exist in current document\

Comment: @Prasanna - querieddata=(from oUser in context.User
 join oUserRole in context.UserRole on oUser.Id equals oUserRole.UserI  join oRoleRightsPage in context.RoleRightsPage.Where(i => i.IsActive == true) 
 on oUserRole.RoleId equals oRoleRightsPage.RoleId
join oApplicationPage in context.ApplicationPage.Where(i => i.IsActive == true) on oRoleRightsPage.PageId equals oApplicationPage.Id join oRole in context.Role on oUserRole.RoleId equals oRole.Id  join oEmployee in context.Employee on oUser.EmployeeId equals oEmployee.IdoRole.RoleName,         
 SectionId = oSection.Id
  }).Distinct().ToList();

Answer (score 0):

The `HasFlag` method has no equivalent in Linq to Entities which is why you get that error. You can get around it by using bitwise comparison instead of using `HasFlag`, for example this:

```
((DisplayType)oRoleRightsPage.DisplayType).HasFlag(displayType)
```

Becomes:

```
(oRoleRightsPage.DisplayType & displayType) > 0
```

Comment: operayion & cannot be applied to the operands of type byte